# Naive implementation of a program to generate optimal timetable for college

Tags: python, python-3.x

College registration for the next semester is soon, So I decided to make a naive implementation (Bruteforce) for a program to generate an optimal timetable in terms of number of work days I need to attend. Even though this problem is NP-hard, but that's no problem for the size of input of my problem (6-7 courses maximum)

Here are some things to consider about our courses system:

- Each course can be included in 2 or 3 groups
- A student can register any course from any different group, but you must register the whole course (i.e. section and lab for that course must be the from the same group as the lecture)
- One day is divided into 12 periods, Any part of a course (Lecture, section or lab) can be between 1 to 3 periods.

First, Here's `CollegeSchedule.py` Where I have some classes declaration

```
from collections import defaultdict

workdays = ('Saturday', 'Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wedensday', 'Thrusday')


class Course():

    """
    This class contains infomation about a college course such as course
    name and in which group it occurs in.
    Each course consists of a lecture and a section at least, some courses
    has extra slot for a lab.
    """

    def __init__(self, name):

        self.name = name
        self.occurances = defaultdict(list)

    def add_slot(self, group, day, periods, type_):
        S = Slot(self, group, day, periods, type_)
        self.occurances[group].append(S)

    def get_group_slots(self, group):
        if group in self.occurances:
            return self.occurances[group]
        # In the rare case where a course is only present in 2 groups only
        return None

    def __str__(self):

        result = ""
        for group, slots in self.occurances.items():
            result += "Group " + str(group) + ":\n"
            for slot in slots:
                result += slot.get_type() + "\n"
                result += "Day: " + \
                    str(slot.day) + " Group: " + str(slot.group) + \
                    " Periods: " + str(slot.periods) + "\n"

        return result


class Slot():

    """
    This class represents a slot in a timetable (part of a course), including the
    type of that part (i.e. lecture, section or lab) along with
    the periods in which that part takes place (We've 12 periods per day, each slot
    can be between 1 to 3 periods),
    Day in which that part occurs,
    group number,
    and course name.
    """

    def __init__(self, course, group, day, periods, type_):
        self.course = course.name
        self.group = group
        self.day = day
        self.periods = periods
        self.type = type_

    def get_type(self):
        return self.type

    def __str__(self):
        result = "Course: " + self.course + " Group " + \
            str(self.group) + " " + str(self.type) + \
            " Periods " + str(self.periods)
        return result

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.__str__()


class Timetable:
    """
    A very simple Timetable representation, Has a dictionary with a
    key being the day number and the value is a list of slots
    that are part of the Timetable.
    """

    def __init__(self):
        self.work_days = defaultdict(list)

    def add_course(self, course_slots):
        """
        Tries to add a whole course (Lecture, section and lab) into the timetable.
        Returns boolean indicating if adding was successful.
        """

        if not course_slots:
            return False

        for slot in course_slots:
            can_add = self.check_slot(slot)
            if not can_add:
                return False
            self.work_days[slot.day].append(slot)

        return True

    def check_slot(self, slot):
        """
        Checks if a slot can be added into the Timetable
        by checking if the slot periods intersect with any other slot
        in the same day.
        """
        day = slot.day

        if not day in self.work_days:
            return True

        for t_slot in self.work_days[day]:
            t_time = t_slot.periods
            time = slot.periods
            new_time = (max(t_time[0], time[0]), min(t_time[1], time[1]))

            if new_time[0] <= new_time[1]:
                return False

        return True

    def print_timetable(self):
        """
        Print the timetable in a sorted way.
        First sorted by days, and inside each day sorted by periods.
        """
        days_list = sorted(self.work_days)
        for day in days_list:
            print(workdays[day])
            self.work_days[day].sort(key=lambda x: x.periods[0])
            print(*self.work_days[day], sep="\n")


    def total_days(self):
        return len(self.work_days)
```

And here's the method `generate_best_timetables` which actually generates the timetables

```
def generate_best_timetables(courses, MAX_GROUP_NUM = 3):
    """
    Generating every possible solution to the problem, Here I am Generating
    3**N possible tuples Where 3 is the maximum number of groups and N is the number of
    courses to consider.
    Each element value in the tuple correspond to a group number - 1 (0, 1, 2), and the i-th element
    in the tuple correspond to the i-th course in the list of courses.
    i.e. for i-th element in the tuple, we try to add the tuple[i]+1 group of the i-th
    course to the timetable.
    """

    total_tt = []
    best_tt = None
    COURSES_NUM = len(courses)

    for p in product(range(MAX_GROUP_NUM), repeat=COURSES_NUM):
        tt = Timetable()
        valid = True

        for i, val in enumerate(p):
            course_slots = courses[i].get_group_slots(int(val) + 1)
            valid = tt.add_course(course_slots)
            if not valid:
                break

        if valid:
            # Store all the timetables with minimum number of work days
            if not best_tt or tt.total_days() < best_tt.total_days():
                best_tt = tt
                total_tt = [best_tt]
            elif tt.total_days() == best_tt.total_days():
                total_tt.append(tt)

    return total_tt
```

And example data and main:

```
# Algorithms
algo = Course("Algorithms")
algo.add_slot(1, 0, (1, 2), "Lecture")
algo.add_slot(1, 0, (3, 4), "Section")
algo.add_slot(1, 1, (3, 4), "Lab")

algo.add_slot(2, 0, (1, 2), "Lecture")
algo.add_slot(2, 2, (1, 2), "Section")
algo.add_slot(2, 3, (1, 2), "Lab")

# OS
os = Course("Operating Systems")
os.add_slot(1, 0, (5, 6), "Lecture")
os.add_slot(1, 0, (7, 8), "Section")
os.add_slot(1, 1, (5, 6), "Lab")

os.add_slot(2, 0, (1, 2), "Lecture")
os.add_slot(2, 4, (7, 8), "Section")
os.add_slot(2, 5, (5, 6), "Lab")

def main():
    courses = [os, algo]
    total_tt = generate_best_timetables(courses)

    for tt in total_tt:
        tt.print_timetable()
        print("Working days: ", tt.total_days())
        print("================================")
```

What can I improve about my program?

I know I've problem with naming variables/classes/modules and the classes structure I've right now is not the best and the way I generate the next possible timetable in `generate_best_timetables` using product is kinda odd, and again, Performance is not an issue with the size of my problem so I'm not really considered about it for now.

For testing now, I'm adding the courses in code manually but I'll be populating the courses list from file (maybe csv file?) or database.

I would appreciate any comments on my code.

Comment: You may want to specify what you want (or think can be) improved. Run time, memory efficiency, compile time, readability, etc... Or if you want a more optimal algorithm than bruteforce.

Comment: I'd like a general comment on my code, point out to any possible bugs or improvement in generating the time table function (A better way than using product possibly?). Also any suggestion for a better structure for my classes.

Comment: Are you sure about the spelling of "Wedensday" and "Thrusday"?

Comment: @GarethRees Those are just typos.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Notes:

- Good use of a tuple for `workdays`
- Good use of `defaultdict`
- Decent documentation. Weird wrapping. Should follow some kind of standard.
- Good use of `itertools.product`

Some minor nitpicks:

- [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)! (line length, `"` for format strings, `'` for all other strings, etc.)
- We prefer `class Course:` to `class Course():`
- You should never have a blank line after a line ending in `:`
- You should use an `enum` for the workdays (this will improve readability later on--I had no idea what those numbers in the course initialization meant):

```
class Workday(Enum):
    Saturday = 0
    Sunday = 1
    Monday = 2
    Tuesday = 3
    Wednesday = 4
    Thursday = 5
    # NOTE: Friday missing?
```

- In `get_group_slots` the `in` check isn't very Pythonic. Python subscribes to the try and handle the failure if it happens philosophy. Namely, indexing a nonexistent key in a `dict` will produce an `KeyError`. So that code should look like:

```
def get_group_slots(self, group):
    try:
        return self.occurances[group]
    except KeyError:
        return None
```

- Your `__str__` looks very java-y. We prefer building strings by employing format strings (or f-strings if you're on Python 3.6, which I'll use in this example) and `string.join` (I will add that it is a little strange that you define a `__str__` on `Slot` but don't use it):

```
def __str__(self):
    # This is still a bit unwieldy, but it conveys your intent a bit better 
    def str_slot(slot):
        return f'{slot.get_type()}\nDay: {slot.day} Group: {slot.group} ' \
               f'Periods: {slot.periods}'

    return '\n'.join("Group {}:\n{}".format(group, '\n'.join(map(str_slot, slots)))
                     for group, slots in self.occurances.items())
```

- On `Slot`, defining `__repr__` as `__str__` isn't right in this context. `__repr__` should be unambiguous in its representation of your object. Generally they look like `<Slot ...>`. `__str__` is for pretty printing (as you have defined it)
- `get_type` is strange. Typically in Python we don't do getters and setters. Instead use the [property](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property) decorator. Although, typically most people just expose the value as a regular property (because using the property syntax is verbose)
- Since `Slot` is immutable, it seems like a good candidate to be a [`namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple). This comes with immutable properties and a `__repr__` for free.
- "Private" properties are prefixed with `_` as an indicator
- Logic issue: why does `add_course([])` return `False`? Seems like an empty class should be addable? Which leads me to:
- Your `Course` is a conflation between an object and the builder pattern. It is both at the same time. This is troubling, because typically in a typed language once you are able to `new` an object it should be fully built (and ready to use). I shouldn't need to `thing = SomeThing(); thing.setupMoreStuff()`. I'd actually suggest making `Course` a `namedtuple` too. Add a `@classmethod` called `create` for building a `Course` with a given `name` and `slots` (and perhaps this can `assert` that there is at least one slot). `Slot` doesn't need the first `course` parameter, so you remove the cyclic dependency. The ideal syntax in my mind looks like:

```
class Course(namedtuple('Course', ('name', 'occurances'))):
    @classmethod
    def create(cls, name, slots):
        occurances = defaultdict(list)
        for slot in slots:
            occurances[slot.group].append(slot)

        return cls(name, occurances)

    # ... define __str__ ...

Slot = namedtuple('Slot', ('group', 'day', 'periods', 'type'))

# Example Usage:
algorithms_course = Course.create('Algorithms', [
    # NOTE: Why are the groups 1 indexed!!
    # Note: The periods tuple is confusing.
    Slot(1, Workday.Saturday, (1, 2), 'Lecture'),
    Slot(1, Workday.Saturday, (3, 4), 'Lecture'),
    Slot(1, Workday.Sunday, (3, 4), 'Lab'),
    Slot(2, Workday.Saturday, (1, 2), 'Lecture'),
    Slot(2, Workday.Monday, (1, 2), 'Lecture'),
    Slot(2, Workday.Tuesday, (1, 2), 'Lab'),
])
```

- Similarly to before the `check_slot` and `add_course` dance in `Timetable` isn't super pythonic. `add_slot` should try to add and raise a special exception like `ScheduleConflictError` in the event it can't be added. You can still have the two separate methods, but I'd make `check_slot` "private" (by prefixing with `_`)
- Your defining of periods as tuples makes `check_slot` confusing. I'd name periods `namedtuple`s as well and add an `overlaps()` method. Then `_check_slot()` becomes one line: `return any(slot.overlaps(other_slot) for other_slot in self.work_days[slot.day])`
- Making periods `namedtuple`s also gives them a default ordering that will sort by the first element then the next (which is how you want periods sorted in `print_timetable`). Then you can define `__lt__` on `Slot` and then sorting the slots for printing is just `sorted(self.work_days[day])` (prefer this to `.sort()`, which mutates the underlying list unless that's what you want)
- Again in `print_timetable` prefer `string.join` and f-strings
- In `generate_best_timetables`:

  - **Never** use `UPPER_SNAKE_CASE` except for constants
  - Prefer `x is None` to `not x`
  - Instead of maintaining `best_tt` and `total_tt`, I would maintain a single `list`. When you find ties `append()` to the list. When you find a better one `clear()` the list. I'd call this collection `best_timetables`. We prefer no abbreviations. You can compare total days like so: `best_timetables[0].total_days()`:

```
best_timetables = deque()

# ... snip ...

if valid:
    try:
        if tt.total_days() < best_timetables[0].total_days():
            best_timetables = [tt]
        elif tt.total_days() == best_timetables[0].total_days():
            best_timetables.append(tt)
    except IndexError:
        best_timetables = [tt]

- I wouldn't use `tt`. `current_timetable` is better.
- You don't need the `int(val)`. `val` is already an int
- The `valid` flag isn't very pythonic. And if you take my advice about raising `ScheduleConflictErorr`, then you can remove it and do the much more pythonic:
```

```
best_timetables = []

for p in product(range(max_group_num), repeat=len(courses)):
    try:
        current_timetable = Timetable()

        # NOTE: Prefer zip() to indexing
        for course, val in zip(courses, p):  # NOTE: name p better, what is it?
            timetable.add_course(course.occurances[val + 1])  # NOTE: val + 1 is still unclear, better naming may help here

        try:
            if tt.total_days() < best_timetables[0].total_days():
                best_timetables = [tt]
            elif tt.total_days() == best_timetables[0].total_days():
                best_timetables.append(tt)
        except IndexError:
            best_timetables = [tt]
    except ScheduleConflictError:
        pass

- Generate your `courses` inside `main()` right before `courses`!
```

- This file should be called `college_schedule.py` not `CollegeSchedule.py`

Comment: I've gone through your comment a couple of times, it makes a lot of sense, Friday is missing because I'm from Egypt -_I don't go to college by Camel!_- , Friday is the weekend day. In my original code `add_course([])` or rather `add_course(None)` in some sense should be addable, but the problem here is I'm generating all possibilities for say, 3 groups (max) and 3 courses,  but if first group only happens to be only in 2 groups, possibility `222` can't happen as the first course has no slots in that group and I have to take that course in solution.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your effort and notes! I'll read your notes a couple more times and go through improving my code, I'll end up making an update post if I improve it further more.